# C# Enums: Nullable or 'Unknown' Value?

Tags: c#, enums

If I have a class with an `enum` member and I want to be able to represent situations where this member is not defined, which is it better?

a) Declare the member as nullable in the class using nullable types. E.g.:

```
public SomeEnum? myEnum;
```

b) Add a default, 'unknown' value to the enumeration. E.g.:

```
public enum SomeEnum {
    Unknown,
    SomeValueA,
    SomeValueB,
    SomeValueC,
}
```

I can't really see any major pros/cons either way; but perhaps one is preferable over the other?

Comment: This question should really be tagged 'Subjective'.

Comment: Well if the question sounds subjective, it's only down to my lack of knowledge. If there are solid reasons why one should be used over the other then it's not really subjective.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Definitely use a nullable value type - that's what they're for. It explicitly states your intention. It also means you can use [`Enum.IsDefined`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx) (or the equivalent from [Unconstrained Melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) if you want generic type safety) to easily determine whether a particular value is a *real* value without worrying about the "fake" one too.

Comment: Interesting. Related: Why does FxCop complain about enumerations without a zero value (i.e. in enums that assign explicit values for each entry),  suggesting a "None" entry with value 0? Doesn't it seem like adding an artificial "None" is a "fake" value like your answer states, therefore being an inferior solution? See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182149(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Perhaps the FxCop rule is older than nullable types?

Comment: Yeah, it's going back to my point about if you use a nullable then you get a sensible default, which is what that rule is trying to enforce.

Comment: Good explanation, just checked out the code for the Unconstrained Melody project, very interesting stuff. I wonder what could with combining the DelegateConstraint concept with linq expressions...

Comment: Just had a discussion about this with my colleague, but if Jon Skeet says use nullable I guess my argument is invalid :)

Comment: @JonSkeet I think @MarkCarpenter misunderstood the FxCop rule. The [docs for CA1008](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1008) only insist on a 'None' value for flag enums. For simple enums, it merely requires that a zero value is specified where that value is the most frequently used value. A nullable enum is valid where the variable is undefined (just like choosing between `int` and `int?`), but that is outside the scope of this rule which is only to protect against the enum being initialised to 0 without having a valid zero value (as enum is `Int32` by default).

Comment: @Neo: Right, that would make sense.

Answer (score 28):

I agree with archimed7592 that there is a real difference between absent value and "Unknown" value.

Example:

"what is your blood type?"

- Null = absent value --> question hasn't been answered --> ask the question
- "Unknown" --> patient indicates he doesn't know --> order lab test for the blood type

Answer (score 8):

You just have to decide whether you need a value to represent unknown values, or you do need a way to represent absence of any value.

In the case of a need to represent unknown values, an extra enum-member sounds good as a solution.

In case of a need to represent absence of any value, make it nullable.

Have in mind, that there is nothing wrong with having both "unknown" enum-member and the enum itself being nullable at the same time.

HTH.

Answer (score 5):

**IT DEPENDS!**

Bill Wagner has listed some good reasons to add an *Undefined* `enum` when it makes sense. I suggest that you find the full item, but here's a preview:

> Item 8: Ensure That 0 Is a Valid State for Value Types
>
> The default .NET system initialization sets all objects to all 0s. There is no way for you to prevent other programmers from creating an instance of a value type that is initialized to all 0s. Make that the default value for your type.
>
> One special case is enums. Never create an enum that does not include 0 as a valid choice. All enums are derived from System.ValueType. The values for the enumeration start at 0, but you can modify that behavior...

Now, I have a situation where the users need to select some type from a ComboBox, or they can have no type selected. I am using an enum with a `[Description("a description")]` attribute as the object to be selected. If none/Unknown is a natural choice for an enum, then I would use that to represent that nothing is selected. Otherwise, I will use a `Nullable<MyEnum>`.

Answer (score 2):

If it's nullable, you'd get it as a default value, you'd get exceptions if you tried to use it when null (which is a good thing!)

Answer (score 1):

Everything changes if the enum is attributed with `[Flags]` Attribute.

```
    [Flags]
    enum FlagsEnum
    {
        None = 0,
        First = 1,
        Second = 2,
        Third = 4,
        FirstAndThird = 5
    }
```