ASP.NET MVC is returning 0 for form control enum dropdown when creating an item
Creating an ASP.NET MVC test project, and I am attempting to add a category dropdown from an enum inside my submit form to create a product. The categories appear in the dropdown accurately, but they don't map to the model and instead I get returned a 0.
Here's my code:
public enum Category
{
    Electronics = 1,
    Clothing,
    Home,
    Kitchen,
    Beauty
}

public class Product
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}

View:
<form asp-action="CreateProduct" method="post">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name of product" asp-for="Name" required />

    <label class="mt-4">Description</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Description of product" asp-for="Description" required />

    <label class="mt-4">Price</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Price of product" asp-for="Price" step="0.01" required />

    <label class="mt-4">Category</label>
    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(x => x.Category,
                              "Select Category",
                              new { @class = "form-control" })
    <input class="btn btn-primary mt-4" type="submit" value="CreateProduct"></input>
</form>

Create methods:
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
{
    var enumData = from Category c in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Category))
       select new
       {
           ID = (int)c,
           Name = c.ToString()
       };

    ViewBag.EnumList = new SelectList(enumData, "ID", "Name");

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateProduct(Product product)
{
    try
    {
        string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
        StringContent content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage response = _client.PostAsync(_client.BaseAddress + "/CreateProduct", content).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            TempData["successMessage"] = "Product created successfully!";
            return RedirectToAction("Products");
        }

        return View("ErrorPage");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        TempData["errorMessage"] = ex.Message;
        return View("ErrorPage");
    }
}

Tried a few different ways of setting up the view, though I may be mixing up my versions. Tried using DropDownList and Html.GetEnumSelectList in place of EnumDropDownListFor.

The return value will be integer. You expect it to be string?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554577/how-to-tell-if-an-enum-property-has-been-set-c-sharp can be help

I'm looking for an integer between 1 and 5 for the enum class I'm testing, but it's always 0 in return instead which is what I'm confused by, even though the view shows the value I'm selecting

As I said inside the answer the EnumDropDownListFor is for old version 5.2.6 MVCSelectExtensions, the new asp.net core is using the HtmlHelperSelectExtensions, you should use the DropDownListFor instead of the EnumDropDownListFor. Then it will generate the right html tag which contains the right name attribute which caused the model binder bind the model well inside the CreateProduct method.

According to your codes, it seems you are using the .net core, .net core doesn't contain the EnumDropDownListFor method , if you are using the old version's MVC method , it will still bind the model fail.
I suggest you could modify the dropdown and use the  Html.GetEnumSelectList to generate the select list.
More details, you could refer to below codes:
<form asp-action="CreateProduct" asp-controller="home" method="post">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name of product" asp-for="Name" required />

    <label class="mt-4">Description</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Description of product" asp-for="Description" required />

    <label class="mt-4">Price</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Price of product" asp-for="Price" step="0.01" required />

    <label class="mt-4">Category</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Category, Html.GetEnumSelectList<Category>(), "Select Category", new { @class = "form-control" })

    <input class="btn btn-primary mt-4" type="submit" value="CreateProduct" />
</form>

Result:

