# Initialize enum with a null value

Tags: c#, .net

How do i create an enum with a null value

ex:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [StringValue("X")]
    MyX,
    [StringValue("Y")]
    MyY,      
    None
}
```

where None value is null or String.Empty

Comment: `[StringValue("")]` or `[StringValue(null)]` doesn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set enum to null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337193/how-to-set-enum-to-null)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can try something like this:-

```
public MyEnum? value= null;
```

or you can try this:-

```
 public MyEnum value= MyEnum.None;
```

Comment: Although his question asks for that answer it isn't what he was asking.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for a member of an enum to have a `null` value.

Comment: @jsobo what they are asking is impossible; this is fine as an answer IMO

Comment: Sorry to be so obtuse.  The answer definitely answers what was asked.  However I strongly believe the question was actually about how to allow MyEnum.None to have a StringValue of string.empty.

Answer (score 5):

use the "?" oeprator for a nullable type !!

```
public MyEnum? myEnum= null;
```

Answer (score 5):

As all the other answers said, you **can't** have an enum value be null.
What you **can** do is add a `Description` attribute (like your `StringValue`) which has a null value.

For instance:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Description(null)]
    None = 0,
    [Description("X")]
    MyX,
    [Description("Y")]
    MyY
}
```

You can get the description of the Enum with the following function:

```
    public static string GetEnumDescription(Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
            (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
            typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
            false);

        if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
            return attributes[0].Description;
        else
            return value.ToString();
    }
```

**Usage:**

```
MyEnum e = MyEnum.None;
string s2 = GetEnumDescription((MyEnum)e); // This returns null
```

Answer (score 4):

All enum types are value types and the different members are also derived from member types (the allowed types are `byte`, `sbyte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, or `ulong` - as [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx)).

This means that members of an enumeration cannot be `null`.

One way to deal with a default `enum` value is to put the `None` value as the first value and setting it to a negative value (for signed enums) or `0`.

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [StringValue(null)]
    None = -1,
    [StringValue("X")]
    MyX,
    [StringValue("Y")]
    MyY      
}
```

You can have a `null` reference to an enumeration if you declare a nullable instance - `myenum?`.

Comment: The value None should always have a value of 0.

Comment: @erikkallen - Why should it always be 0.  It could also be -1, it actually could by any value, that cannot actually be a real value in the given situation.

Comment: Because the default initializer of an enum will set the enum to `(MyEnum)0`. [FxCop agrees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182149(v=vs.80).aspx). Perhaps None shouldn't be the default always though, eg. if you have an enum of "negative options", perhaps `All` should be the default value.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as an "enum with a null value". An enum in C# is just a named integer. In your case, `None` is just an alias for `2` (for completeness, `MyX` is `0` and `MyY` is `1`). By default, the underlying data-type of an enum is `int`, but it can also be other integer-based primitive types of different sizes/sign.

If you want a "null" enum, you would have to use `MyEnum?`, aka `Nullable<MyEnum>`.