# Removing Null from all enums in a solution

Tags: c#, .net, enums, null

Following the responses from the below questions and answers, is it really worth the effort to remove all the Null instances from a middle-weight [50,000 lines] project if that Null value has never been used throughout the entire project? It might look like a simple right click in resharper but is it really worth the effort? What would I gain? Just a better-practice code?

[Is it a good practice to add a “Null” or “None” member to the enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151354/is-it-a-good-practice-to-add-a-null-or-none-member-to-the-enum)

[C# Enums: Nullable or 'Unknown' Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795657/c-sharp-enums-nullable-or-unknown-value)

Comment: That last sentence makes people downvote and vote to close...

Comment: Are you asking whether you should remove an enum value that isn't used? If it isn't used, why bother leaving it?

Comment: Yes, it has not been used.

Comment: If you have unused code, and it doesn't have any purpose at all, why keep it?

Answer (score 2):

Whether you should delete an unused "None/null" value of an enum is identical to your answer to the question [whether you believe you should have "None/null" value](http://sprout.stanford.edu/PAPERS/LICS-SBDL-2001.pdf). If you think they should not exist, delete it. If you think it should exist keep it.

I believe this question is a tiny extension of the already existing question. Deleting an unused enum member is a one-line change that is easily reversible.

One possible pitfall is that removing an enum member changes the output of `Enum.ToString`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this enum:

```
enum Color { None, Red, Green, Blue }
```

This will print "None":

```
Console.WriteLine(default(Color));
```

If you remove the `None`, that statement will print something else.

If will print "0" if you do this:

```
enum Color { Red = 1, Green, Blue }
```

It will print "Red" if you do this:

```
enum Color { Red, Green, Blue }
```

In addition, the latter change will have an impact on serialized values.

Be careful when assuming a `None` value is not used, simply because you see no reference to it in code.

Similar observations apply to this code:

```
var colors = new Color[10];

Console.WriteLine(colors[0]);
```

or

```
var color = (Color) 1;
```

Comment: Very good point Kris. Those Null enums are sitting there in the code doing no harm to me right now but I think removing them could be the start of trouble.

Comment: @Socrates Their "harm" is mostly limited to some metadata. When in doubt, don't change working code for such little potential benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the different aspects, some pros for removing the unused enum values:

- Removing unused code is usually good for making it more readable and maintainable.
- Values without a purpose can cause confusion.

and some possible pitfalls:

- An unused enum value might still have a purpose for documentation by just existing.
- An unused enum value might still affect what value other enum values get.
- Changing code always has a potential risk of introducing bugs.