# Setting Nullable Enum to $null - Should this really cause PSInvalidCastException?

Tags: .net, powershell, enums, powershell-3.0, nullable

Setting a Nullable Enum to $null in PowerShell causes a`System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidCastException` exception.  This is unexpected (to me at least). Is there a reasonable explanation for this? Here is an example that shows how setting a Nullable Int32 is successful, but setting a Nullable Enum causes an exception:

```
Add-Type @"
public enum ColorEnum
{
    Red = 1,
    Blue = 2,
    Green = 3,
}

public class Thing
{
    public ColorEnum? NullableColor = ColorEnum.Blue;
    public System.Int32? NullableInt = 123;
}
"@

$test = New-Object Thing

# Setting the Nullable Int32 to $null works, as expected.
$test.NullableInt = $null

# Setting the Nullable Enum to $null causes exception.
$test.NullableColor = $null
```

The exception message reads:

> *Exception setting "NullableColor": "Cannot convert null to type "ColorEnum" due to enumeration values that are not valid. Specify one
>   of the following enumeration values and try again. The possible
>   enumeration values are  "Red, Blue, Green"."*

The reason I would like to be able to use a Nullable Enum, rather than an Enum with a default value of 0, is because the Enum I want to use represents a nullable database column which is expected to be null when no valid value is set.  I cannot change the database model, so unfortunately it feels like the solution may be to use an Int32 instead of an Enum.

Has anyone else experienced this?  Is it a bug perhaps?

$PsVersionTable:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                            
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                            
PSVersion                      3.0                                                                                                                                                                                              
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                                                              
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                                                                                                                          
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.18444                                                                                                                                                                                  
BuildVersion                   6.2.9200.16481                                                                                                                                                                                   
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}                                                                                                                                                                                  
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Comment: It looks like a bug to me. You can submit it here - https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/Feedback

Comment: Looks like a bug to me too. GJ in finding it. Here is a link with more about nullable enums: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337193/how-to-set-enum-to-null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a bug in PowerShell 4 (and probably 3, but I haven't tried it).

It has been fixed in PowerShell V5 (verified against recent internal builds), I believe it should be fixed in public builds like the September WMF5 preview or Windows 10 preview builds.