# How to return null for a method whose return type is enum?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, return-type

I have an enum which have some values

```
public enum CompareOperators
{            
        GreaterThan,
        LessThan,
        GreaterThanEqualTo,
        LessThanEqualTo,
        EqualTo,
        NotEqualTo
}
```

I have a method which returns this enum for various conditions

```
public static CompareOperators GetTypeForOperator(string strType)
{
      switch (strType)
      {
             case "=":
                return CompareOperators.EqualTo;
             case "!=":
                return CompareOperators.NotEqualTo;
             case ">":
                return CompareOperators.GreaterThan;
             case "<":
                return CompareOperators.LessThan;
             case ">=":
                return CompareOperators.GreaterThanEqualTo;
             case "<=":
                return CompareOperators.LessThanEqualTo;
     }
     return null;
}
```

I am getting the following error while compiling

```
Cannot convert null to CompareOperators because it is not a non-nullable value type
```

What is the best way to return `null` when no condition is satisfied inside `switch` statement?

Even though I looked for below questions, I didn't get an answer for my solution

- [How can I return NULL from a generic method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302096/how-can-i-return-null-from-a-generic-method-in-c)
- [How to set enum to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337193/how-to-set-enum-to-null)

Comment: I would throw an exception instead of returning null.

Comment: Just a bit out of context, but I would then call it GetTypeORDefaultForOperator and use nullable type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make your method return a nullable `CompareOperators`:

```
public static CompareOperators? GetTypeForOperator(string strType)
```

The `?` after the type name makes it nullable. Another options it to use this, which is the same:

```
public static Nullable<CompareOperators> GetTypeForOperator(string strType)
```

See [MSDN on Using Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx).

Another option, as already mentioned, it to throw an exception or return a 'default' value like `CompareOperators.Unknown`, but that is totally up to you. What the best solution is, is based on your requirements and preferred writing style.

---

End result:

```
public static CompareOperators? GetTypeForOperator(string strType)
{
    switch (strType)
    {
        case "=":
            return ...
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

(Check for null afterwards):

```
var x = GetTypeForOperator("strType");
if (x != null)
{ ... }
```

Or:

```
public static CompareOperators GetTypeForOperator(string strType)
{
    switch (strType)
    {
        case "=":
            return ...
        default:
            return CompareOperators.Unknown;
    }
}
```

Or:

```
public static CompareOperators GetTypeForOperator(string strType)
{
    switch (strType)
    {
        case "=":
            return ...
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("strType has a unparseable value");
    }
}
```

Comment: Since it is exact suggestion from linked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337193/how-to-set-enum-to-null it is unlikely to help OP... (and duplicate answer).

Comment: just a default case in switch could help.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: You are right. I updated the answer to be a tailored answer for the user's specific problem.

Answer (score 4):

You should not return null in that case but rather throw exception in `default` block

```
switch (strType)
{
  //...other cases

  default:
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unrecognized comparison mode");
}
```

as without correct parameter you're not able to continue and exceptions are meant for such case when program faces unexpected conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend your enum with an undefined comparison

```
public enum CompareOperators
{
    Undefined,
    GreaterThan,
```

and then return that as default/fallback value

```
return CompareOperators.Undefined;
```