# Cast to value type 'Enum' failed as the materialized value is null. Either the result type's param or query must use nullable type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a variable status defined in following entity:

```
public class Item
    {
        public string ItemNumber { get; set; }
        public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public Status status { get; set; }
    }
```

Enum:

```
public enum Status
    {
        Approved = 1,
        Received = 2,
        Issued = 3,
        PendingApproval = 4,
        Rejected = 5,
        Invoiced = 6,
        Transfered = 7
    }
```

this is the linq:

```
IEnumerable<Item> rpo = (from ro in _db.rpo.Where(c=> c.Id == WorkingId))
                         select new Items 
                         {
                           ItemId = ro.Id
                           ItemDescription = ro.Description
                           ItemNum = ro.Number
                           ItemStatus = ro.Status
                         }.ToList();
```

I am getting this error at linq

> The cast to value type 'Enum' failed because the materialized value is
>   null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use
>   a nullable type.

Kindly let me know how to set the nullable type for the parameter

Updated the question

Comment: can you please post the rpo and item entity ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set enum to null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337193/how-to-set-enum-to-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an enum is a value type, it cannot be `null`. A way around that is to use a nullable type instead:

```
public System.Nullable<Status> Status { get; set; }
```

or the shorthand syntax:

```
public Status? Status { get; set; }
```

This can be done for any value type (int, bool, double etc.).

A nullable type exposes the properties `HasValue` and `Value` which allows you to check whether an actual valid value has been assigned.

Answer (score 3):

You can check in your query if the retrieved value is null:

```
IEnumerable<Item> rpo = (from ro in _db.rpo.Where(c=> c.Id == WorkingId))
                         select new Items 
                         {
                           ItemId = ro.Id
                           ItemDescription = ro.Description
                           ItemNum = ro.Number
                           ItemStatus = ro.Status ?? Status.None
                         }.ToList();
```

Where you have a new value in your enum, *None*. Or you choose one of the existing values.

The `??` checks if the variable in front of `??` is null. If it isn't, use that value, else use the value specified after `??`. More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Ofcourse, your *ro.Status*  has to be `Nullable` to check if it can be null.

Comment: I tried your answer but then the error at ro.Status (Status is the column in DB of Type int.) says Left operand of '??' operator should be of reference or nullable. Any suggestion to work around this issue?

Comment: Set the status column as nullable