# How to do null check for enum

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

```
 public class myclass
    {
        public Details DetailsInfo { get; set; }
        public string name{ get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int subjects{ get; set; }
    }

public enum subjects{
maths,
english,
science,
}
```

Among these subjects is an enum. Even if I don't enter any value for subjects it takes 0 by default. This is the behavior of enum. Is there any way to check if I have chose any value for subject.

Note: I don't want to any value like undefined in the enum.

Comment: That the reason why any Enum should have a `None` value that represents 0. You can use a nullable enum.

Comment: Enum is not a `class` (or, to be more precise, not a reference type). Hence it does not have `null` as value. If you want enum to have `null`, you could use nullable enum: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337193/how-to-set-enum-to-null

Answer (score 5):

You could solve the issue in two ways.

First, define a `None` value (or whatever you want to name it) which represents `0` to indicate there is nothing chosen for an `enum` value:

```
public enum subjects{
    None = 0, //define this
    maths,
    english,
    science,
}
```

Alternatively, use `Nullable<subjects>` or `subjects?` in your class (`myclass`).

```
public class myclass
{
    public Details DetailsInfo { get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public subjects? subj { get; set; } //note the question mark ?
}
```

Of the two methods, the first one is more common. Thus I would rather use the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the class to look like this:

```
 public class myclass
    {
        public Details DetailsInfo { get; set; }
        public string name{ get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public subjects? subject { get; set; }
    }
```

So that the subject is nullable. It means that when you have not set it. It will be null