# How to add and use null value in Enum?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

See below enum contains two members: Test and Production

```
public enum OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRQTarget
{      
    Test,      
    Production,
}
```

I'm looking for the way to add and use Null value in above enum from code like :

```
inv.Target = OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRQTarget.Null; // Not allowed
```

**Update:**
I do not want to add extra `NULL` in above enum, I want to make this dynamic because the above enum is auto generated. and should be remain same.

Is there a way to achieve this in a method itself i.e without creating any `Class` or adding extra `Enum` value in enum?
like : `inv.Target = OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRQTarget.Null;`

How can I do this?

Comment: `Enum` is serialized and presented as numeric (by default `int`). You can use non-existing value as a sign of invalid entry, e.g. `inv.Target = (MyEnum)-1;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlining values of an [`enum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx) are `int` which can't be assigned to `null`.

If you still want to do so:

1. Add `Null` as an option to the enum:

   ```
   public enum OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRQTarget
   {
       Null,
       Test,
       Production
   }
   ```
2. Have your target a Nullable type:

   ```
   Nullable<OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRQTarget> t = null;

   //Or in a cleaner way:
   OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRQTarget? t = null;

   //And in your class:
   public class YourType
   {
       public OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRQTarget? Target { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Comment: option two looks good, how can I use this in place of line : `inv.Target = OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRQTarget.Null;`

Comment: @RSH - please explain. Didn't understant

Comment: `OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRQTarget? t = null;` using this code gives me error that `OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRQTarget` is a `type` but used like variable.

Comment: I replace the code like : `inv.Target = OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRQTarget? t = null;`

Comment: ya.. that won't work.. You need to replace the type of `Target` from `OTA_HotelInvCountNot‌​ifRQTarget` to `OTA_HotelInvCountNot‌​ifRQTarget?`

Comment: @RSH - Did the additional explanation helped you with your question?

Comment: Another option would be to set it as a Flag Enum and set to 0 but that's not much different to your option 1 and would allow `Test & Production` as a value

Comment: @GiladGreen: Thanks! Yes given examples work for me, but in our case I want to do this in a function itself, I can't add extra `class` like you suggested in ex. 2 or extra `Null` value in `Enum` in ex. 1, Is there any way to do it in single line of code or can it be done inside method itself?

Comment: @RSH- you can assign -1 because it is not in your email values and then it'll not match to anything - closest to having it null without actually changing it to a nullable type. My personally - I would not do it and would change the class/enum

Comment: @RSH - In 2 I didn't suggest an extra class - but to change the property in your original class

Comment: Thank you so much @Gilad Green :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRQTarget
{    
    Null,  
    Test,      
    Production
}
```

also answewred here
[How to set enum to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337193/how-to-set-enum-to-null)

Comment: Close, but you probably want Null to be the first entry so it's the default.

Comment: I want to do this from code, means from where I'm using these enum.. I dont want to add extra value i.e. `Null` in it

Comment: then i suggest you should google, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337193/how-to-set-enum-to-null, it was the first google result for `make enum nullable`

Answer (score 0):

`Enum` is `enum`. It value type and you can use 
`Nullable<OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRQTarget>` or `OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRQTarget?` for represent "not set statement"

but if you still want user `null` as `enum` value try

```
public enum OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRQTarget
{
    Null,
    Test,
    Production
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or using the "?" Operator for the variable:

```
public OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRQTarget? Target;
```

You have to change the assignment to:

```
inv.Target = null;
```