# How to handle C# nullable Enum in protobuf

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have nullable enum in my code which I'm trying to define in my .proto file but when I generate the C# class the enum is not nullable. Here is my proto file

```
enum Foo {
   Bar = 0;
   Bat = 1;      
}

message FooBar {
  int32 Id = 1;
  optional Foo Foo = 2;
}
```

I've read about two possible solutions.

1. Use `oneof` but this way I can't set the `Bar` to be `0`
2. Add `Unknown = 0;` but this is not backward compatible with the existing data where the `0` element has different meaning

Is there another options or it is not possible to make `Nullable<Enum>` as of now?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337193/how-to-set-enum-to-null

Maybe this?

Comment: This implies touching the generated .cs file manually which is not viable because everytime I regenerate it using `protoc --csharp_out=.  ./foobar.proto` I will have to edit it.

Comment: if 0 does not work for you as additional value hows -1?

Comment: I would handle it as built in nullable value types are handled: create  wrapper object for your enum and that can be null by default. See built in nullable value types: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/48234f5f012582843bb476ee3afef36cda94cb66/src/google/protobuf/wrappers.proto#L88

Comment: public Foo? Foo = null;